# Hot water only when multiple sources turned on

Tags: plumbing, water, water-heater, hot-water

When one hot water source is turned on, the hot water is only lukewarm. But as soon as another source is simultaneously running, the water runs hot. For example, the kitchen sink runs cold, but if I run the hot water in the nearby bathroom sink both will be hot. Or, we have a downstairs shower with two shower heads: when only one is on the water is cold, but when both are on it's hot.

Can anyone suggest an explanation/remedy?! We have a storage water heater.

Comment: Is this a problem only in the winter?  Or does it do it in the summer too?

Comment: If you run the single source for say, an hour, does it eventually get cold again instead of warm?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica It's only been a problem the last few weeks, so only Winter so far. In Las Vegas, so not the coldest Winter!

Comment: @EricHauenstein I haven't tried: what would this help to diagnose?

Comment: @Holographer I was curious if the temperature would remain warm without getting hot until the tank is empty. If so, all of that heat had to go somewhere and you might be able to find it with an IR camera.  Do you see the same effect with any combination of taps throughout the house?

Comment: It almost seems like one of the mixing valves is cross-feeding cold water into the hot water circuit while off.  Were any of them replaced recently?